# Adaptative gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am doing an Android app and i need put 4 elements or pictures in a activity. My idea is the pictures are distributed in two rows and two colums.
Applications always limits their display to portrait orientation.

I think a gridview is a good solution no? but my question is, how can i do with this gridview to it adapt to everey display?

This is the layout where i define it:

```
<!-- ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? -->
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:numColumns="2" />
```

Some new parameters to this layout??

Thanks

Comment: Try to use GridLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have static number image ( like just 4 image ) better to use `LinearLayout` and set weight for each Image to fill page, but if you don't have static number you need write custom adapter and get height of display then set height if each element to (height / numberRow) in your code.

for first suggest you can use following code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:layout_weight=".5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
         android:layout_weight=".5"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".5" >

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:layout_weight=".5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
         android:layout_weight=".5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

but second suggest its more complicated. you need do following work:

1 - create custom adapter for gridView ( [Developing a custom adapter](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown))

2 - get screen size ([How to get screen dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions))

3 - set height of View in getView to ( height / numberRow )

and set following code to your gridView

```
 android:numColumns="2"
```

this create 2 column in each row

Comment: yes in my application the number of elements is static (4) so your first solution is Ok, thansk so much for your code

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `XML` code:

```
<!-- ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? -->
<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="2" />
```